# HANA Studio locks DB user when accessing HANA in the cloud via database tunnel

Tags: hana, sap-cloud-platform, hana-studio

I'm using the [database tunnel](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?2a795b95e44c42d08c446893a07921db.html) from the SDK of the HANA Cloud Platform to connect to a HANA instance in the cloud. This works fine for the first connection, but I'm having a problem when trying to reconnect after having closed and re-opened the tunnel: The tunnel generates a new password (for the same database user) each time is is opened, but the HANA studio doesn't prompt me for a password when I select "Log On" in the systems view.

Apparently, the studio remembers the previous password and retries that incorrect password until my user is locked: After a while, the system is annotated with a red marker and the status text says

> You have reached the maximum number of invalid password entry attempts. User is locked until ...

I haven't selected the option "Store user name and password in secure storage", but this probably means that the HANA Studio remembers the password until it is restarted. (The [SAP HANA administration guidelines](http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_Administration_Guide_en.pdf) confirm this assumption.)

So, but how do I get out of this situation? How can I unlock my user? And how can I avoid locking it in the future, maybe without having to restart the HANA studio every time I re-open the tunnel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use the new SDK from the SAP HANA Cloud Platform you no longer have a changing password. Once you open the tunnel you'll get an initial password for your HANA instance in the cloud. After changing it to your needs you can always use that database password to connect your HANA Studio to the HANA instance on your account.

But be aware that you have always 2 passwords. The one you use to create the tunnel and the other one that you use in your HANA Studio to connect to your HANA instance in the cloud.

Get the new SDK at https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#cloud

Hope this helps.

Best,
Rui

PS: We'll be repeating the **free** online course "Introduction to SAP HANA Cloud Platform" (https://open.sap.com/course/hanacloud1) around April/May this year. In week 2 and 3 of that course you'll also learn how the "new" tunnel works.